# How to do numerical actions without Collections?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, max, min

I have a quick java program to perform some numerical actions. Right now it uses the Collections library, however the assignment says to not use any of the methods from the java.util.Collections class. What can I switch it out with? Right now I have Collections sorting the ArrayList and also getting the minimum and maximum values.

Thank you.

If you need my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Collections;

class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input:");
    int i = 0;
    int strs = 0;
    strs = input.nextInt();
    while (strs != -1) {
      if(strs > 100 || strs < 0 && strs != -1) {
        strs = input.nextInt();
      }
      else {
        grades.add(strs);
        strs = input.nextInt();
        i++;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("\nOutput:\n");
    System.out.println(grades);
    System.out.println("Sorted:");
    Collections.sort(grades);
    System.out.println(grades);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int g : grades) sum += g;
    double average = sum / grades.size();
    average = 1 * sum / grades.size();
    System.out.println("Average: " + average);
    int mid = grades.size()/2; 
    double median = grades.get(mid); 
    if (grades.size()%2 == 0) { 
      median = (median + grades.get(mid-1))/2; 
    }
    System.out.println("Median: " + median);
    int max = Collections.max(grades);
    int min = Collections.min(grades);
    int range = max - min;
    System.out.println("Range: " + range);
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you can't use collections, it sounds like you need to use double arrays and write your own median, min and max functions.  Not difficult.

Comment: Your instructor probably wants you to use arrays.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you cannot use collections or you cannot use the Collections class.

Comment: The sorting part is the tough one. There are many tutorials on how to do it though.

Comment: From my assignment: "In addition, do not use any of the methods provided by the class java.util.Collections."

Comment: @user866260 Then you will need to write your own max, min and sorting algorithms. For the sorting algorithm (which is the hardish one) you may want to take a look at the Wikipedia articles for [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) and [Mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Comment: Or you can copy your own version of the code in the Collections library.  You have the source in the JDK. (Or searchable on line)